# How to create GoogleMaps/OSM hyperlink for given bbox coordinates

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps, coordinates, extents, hyperlink

I have extracted the bbox coordinates from a shapefile and want to create a hyperlink for google maps respectively OSM. When you click on the hyperlink the map should be zoomed to the bbox extend and most perfectly the bounding rectangle should be rendered. Do you know how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: It would be ok just to know the format and parameters of a osm/google maps hyperlink. Like coordinates, zoom factor and maybe some additional render information if it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Openstreetmap, the parameters are quite simple:

https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=10/47.1911/2.4884

```
https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=  : base url
10/                                 : zoom level
47.1911/                            : latitude of center, North positive
2.4884                              : longitude of center, East positive
```

additionally with a marker:

https://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=47.1911&mlon=2.4884#map=10/47.1911/2.4884

```
https://www.openstreetmap.org/?   : base url
mlat=47.1911&                    : latitude of marker
mlon=2.4884#                     : longitude of marker
map=10/                          : zoom level
47.1911/                         : latitude of center
2.4884                           : longitude of center
```